# How to sort different urls ending with numbers in java or scala?

Tags: java, scala

I have a requirement where I have multiple URLS like this:-

```
http://www.impecablesolns/libs/opt/abc/2.1.html
http://debinz.slousn/abc/def/hello/brain/2.5.html
http://www.impecablesolns/libs/opt/abc/1.9.html
```

I have to sort them and get the latest version like in the above case it will be `http://debinz.slousn/abc/def/hello/brain/2.5.html`,how to do it in java or scala...

Comment: Is the structure of the URL is always `http://some_text/version_number.html`? The first URL contains underscore before the version.

Comment: FYI your urls are different ! how would did you pick http://debinz.slousn/abc/def/hello/brain/2.5.html ?

Comment: Take a look at `Seq.sortBy` or `Seq.maxBy`

Comment: @TDG only numbers are there I edited the question

Comment: Step one is to always always always describe, in words, how **you** (as a human being) would accomplish the task. You haven't done that here, and without that sort of detail you can't possibly expect anyone to help. I mean, it looks to me like if you cut off after the last slash, and before `.html`, you could sort as a number. But I'm only guessing because you haven't said. And there's all sorts of unanswered questions still (is `1.9.4.html` a possibility?)

Comment: @dcsohl, all contains same no of digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val urls = List("http://www.impecablesolns/libs/opt/abc/2.1.html",
                "http://debinz.slousn/abc/def/hello/brain/2.5.html",
                "http://www.impecablesolns/libs/opt/abc/1.9.html")
```

Create a regexp to match the number. Tweak to your requirement:

```
val Version = """/(\d\.\d)\.html$""".r.unanchored
```

Now just find the biggest, according to the number extracted

```
urls.maxBy { case Version(x) => x.toDouble }
//> res0: String = http://debinz.slousn/abc/def/hello/brain/2.5.html
```